# When a handler is attached with addEventListener, it is in which property in event.target?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

When I use `$0.onclick = function() {console.log('click')}`, I can access the handler with the code: `$0.onclick`.

```
function () {console.log('click')}
```

When I use `$el.addEventListener('click',handler, false)`...
How do I access the handler?

Comment: huh? what does the question have to do with the title? - unless you are using arrow functions, `this` is the element that fired the event

Comment: Please read this and edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ...you?...I see....no I don't

Comment: @JaromandaX use your own ideas of knowledge and experience...  it's clear.

Comment: `How do I access the handler?` - in the code, `handler` is a function ... you don't "access" it, you "write" it

Comment: @JaromandaX haha, I want to know that it's stored in which property. you know ...

Comment: the handler is not in the event, the event is the argument to the handler (I really can't figure out your question)

Comment: @JaromandaX well, the handler is not in the event, where is it? that's my question.

Comment: the handler is a function, in this case called handler, you would've written it yourself

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, but it must be referred  by some property? 

Comment: **must**? that's where you are wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I get the `handler` in `element object` with `getEventListeners`

Comment: Yes. That works in the developer tools console. I didn't realise you were asking about the console only

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you brother  感动，嘭嘭嘭

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
document.onclick = function() {console.log(1)}
var evts = getEventListeners(document)
evts.click[1].listener()
```

reference：[monitorEvent](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events?hl=en)